# Qt scrollbar pushes table inwards?

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a window in Qt C++ where inside I fill a table with items row by row. However, after I fill out enough rows, a scrollbar appears in order to allow me to scroll the extra rows. The problem is - when the scrollbar appears, it squeezes the table inwards. Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Will setting the verticalScrollBarPolicy to ScrollBarAlwaysOn  help?  At least the table rows will be the same width no matter how many rows are present.

Comment: perhaps you can pass your own scrollbar with setVerticalScrollbar, which has a width of 0, but paints onto its tabular widget's parent (or has a separate child of that widget that it repositions), overlaying the table contents.